# Meaning of an Integral Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the  transform of $f(t)$ as follows :

$G(t) =\displaystyle \int_{0}^t f(\tau)e^{-2\pi i\Theta} d\tau   \hspace {0.5 in}   \Theta = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\tau} w(x)dx$

What is the meaning of this Transform

Comment: Define "meaning"? ...

Comment: This is the convolution. $H*g$, of $H$ and $g$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function and $g(t)=f(t) e^{-i2\pi \int_0^t w(x)\,dx}$